# error scala: recursive value variable needs type

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have this snippet of code which should create dataframe for each hive table:

```
for (e <- df_tables) {
    val v(df_tables.indexOf(e)) = hiveObj.sql("select * from database."+ e +" order by event_date")
}
```

the `df_tables` is a dataframe and `v` is an array of names i have chosen for those dataframe.

```
df_tables: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([conversionevents], [elements], [pageviews], [productviews], [registrations], [sitepromotionclicks])
```

I got two errors when I've ran this code:

```
<console>:145: error: recursive value e needs type
                  val v(df_tables.indexOf(e)) = hiveObj.sql("select * from database."+ e +" order by event_date")
                                                                                              ^
<console>:145: error: value v is not a case class constructor, nor does it have an unapply/unapplySeq method
                  val v(df_tables.indexOf(e)) = hiveObj.sql("select * from database."+ e +" order by event_date")
```

Comment: can you share the data of df_tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val v = df_tables.map((r: Row) => hiveObj.sql("select * from database."+ r +" order by event_date"))
```

I suspect all the issues were caused by trying to create a value on every iteration, with `val v(df_tables.indexOf(e))`. If you remove the `val`, your code should also work

Comment: the `_` replace what here?

Comment: `error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => "select * from dataset.".$plus(x$1).$plus(" order by event_date"))` what is wrong ?

Comment: maybe I should use : `val v = df_tables.map(x => hiveObj.sql("select * from dataset."+ x +" order by event_date"))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176858/discussion-between-joel-berkeley-and-hisi).